# How to enable comments options?

Tags: comments

1. On page --> Screen Options --> check Discussion --> Discussion --> Allow commets --> I have checked on discussion options.
2. Settings --> Discussion --> I have checked on *Allow people to post comments on new articles*.
3. I also have this code in my theme: `<?php comments_template(); ?>`

But the comment form is still not visible. What else do I have to do?

Comment: Stating the obvious, are you checking the right template?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `page.php` template of your theme and check if `<?php comments_template(); ?>` is added there. If it isn't, then you need to add this line below your page content rendering section.

Comment: Yes, i have already add <?php comments_template(); ?> this code in page.php. but, still not enable comments option.